# Prove that real-values function $f$ on the interval $(x_0 - r , x_0 + r)$, is analytic at $x_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, power-series

Let F be a holomorphic function defined in an open disk $D(x_0, r)$ where $x_0 ∈ R$.
Define a function $f$ in the interval $(x_0 − r, x_0 + r)$ by $f(x) = F(x$) for all
$x ∈ (x-0 − r, x_0 + r)$. Suppose that $f$ is a real-valued function on the interval
$(x_0 − r, x_0 + r)$. Prove that f is analytic at $x_0$.

I know that since $F$ is holomorphic in the open disk, $F$ has the power series representation that is also analytic in the open disk.

How do I use that to prove the real-valued function is analytic at $x_0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-x_0)^n$ be the  power series representation in $D(x_0,r)$. Then

$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-x_0)^n$ for all $ x \in (x_0 − r, x_0 + r).$

Now use $f(x) \in \mathbb R$ for $ x \in (x_0 − r, x_0 + r)$ , to obtain that all $a_n$ are real.